# Remove SXXEXX from file names via powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to remove a certain string from a bunch of files. I'm wanting to remove the "SxxExx" parts. Sometimes there is a letter after the Exx part. Such as the 3rd example.

- Show Name.S01E01.Episode Name1
- Show Name-S01E02-Episode Name2
- Show Name S02E10a Episode Name3

TO

- Show Name.Episode Name1
- Show Name-Episode Name2
- Show Name Episode Name3

These would all be filetype: avi/mkv/mp4

So far I've been using this but it's been removing all numbers

`Get-ChildItem *.avi | % { Rename-Item $_ ([regex]::Replace($_.Name, "[0-9]", "")) }`

Comment: Do you want to rename the file or update their contents? It's not clear

Comment: the `S01E01` info is _season & episode_ info. you are removing the season info and may have name collisions. for instance both `ShowName S01E01 Episode Name1` and `ShowName S02E01 Episode Name1` will map to the same ``ShowName Episode Name1`. so ... are all your episodes named uniquely?

Comment: Naming collisions won't be an issue. The answer below from casenonsenative is exactly what I want just need to figure out how to make it non case sensitive and add .mp4/.mkv with .avi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
Get-ChildItem *.avi | % { Rename-Item $_ ([regex]::Replace($_.Name, "[.- ]?s[0-9]+e[0-9]+", "")) }
```

The regular expression works this way:

[.- ]? will look for a separator that is a dot, a dash or a space or is not available

[0-9]+ will look for at least one number but take as many as possible

e ensures there's an `e` after the numbers

[0-9]+ will look for more numbers and take as many as possible

I can recommend [this site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) for learning more about regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks that works! 2 questions, how would I incorporate (?-i) so the S + E are not case sensitive?

Also for "Get-ChildItem can you list multiple formats?

Comment: you can also use [sS] and [eE] instead of S and E in order to match both cases.